# Ubicacion de opciones de color y cursor tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

estoy aprendiendo el modulo tkinter en python, para esto desarrollo pequeñas GUIS para modificar los argumentos de un widget por medio de los scales pero actualmente me encuentro con el paramaetro de fuente de texto y el de cursor pero no encuentro de cual dependencia, sub modulo, raiz, archivo oatributo extraer los valores posibles para el color y el cursor que algunos de los valores aceptados son strings y por lo mismo quisiera acceder al listado para desplegarlas en la gui para permitir al usuario elegirlas en una lista.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la documentación de Tkinter no es muy exhaustiva al respecto, si que puedes encontrar esta información en la [documentación de TCL/TK](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/contents.htm).

En cuanto al color, puedes definirlo de dos formas:

- Cadena de la forma "#rrggbb" representando el color RGB en forma hexadecimal que quieras.
- Nombres de colores reconocidos por Tkinter, también como una cadena, como `"AntiqueWhite"`, `"aquamarine"`, `"azure"`, `"VioletRed"`, etc.

Por ejemplo, estas dos formas son equivalentes:

```
tk.Button(root, bg="spring green") 
tk.Button(root, bg="#00ff7f")
```

Tienes un listado completo en la documentación de TCL/TK:

[Tk Commands > colors](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/colors.htm)

Ten en cuenta que hay algunos que son exclusivos de cada sistema operativo, tal como aparecen listados en la documentación.

En cuanto al cursor, otro tanto de lo mismo:

[Tk Commands > cursors](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/cursors.htm)

No hay una forma simple e independiente de la plataforma de listar las opciones disponibles en ninguno de los dos casos, al menos que yo sepa, por lo que si quieres ofrecer opciones al usuario te tocara harcodear la lista de las mismas a partir de la documentación.

Comment: Una forma de facilitar el harcodeo de los cursores y colores, sería hacer scrapping a la documentación.

Comment: claro, escribir los valores en el codigo, pero es esto mismo lo que quiero evitar. yo estoy buscando alguna variable en el modulo tkinter que me muestre los valores aceptados pero solo encuentro las variaciones de keys para los parametros pero no los valores que pueden recibir

Comment: Que yo sepa no es posible hacer esto como comento en la respuesta,  los valores de muchos de estos argumentos simplemente no están definidos en ninguna parte del código. Piensa que tkinter es simplemente una interfaz para tcl/tk, tkinter simplemente pasa el argumento (adaptándolo adecuadamente) al interprete tcl asociado que se ejecuta por debajo.